# How does Autofac behave when a new component instance is initialized programmatically that has been registered as a singleton before

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, singleton, autofac

lets say I have a server side app which makes extensive use of a thread safe component. Instead of creating a new component instance every time it is needed, I use Autofac to register, manage and resolve a singleton instance of this component during system startup as described [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#single-instance).

Now my question is: What happens if despite the Autofac registration a new instance of this component is initialized programmatically (`ComponentName c = new ComponentName();`) somewhere in the source code.

Here are my assumptions:

**(Case 1)** If the initialization statement is part of the source code that belongs to the app assembly for which the Autofac DI container has been defined, Autofac will return the registered singleton instance of the component.

**(Case 2)** If the initialization statement is belongs to the source code of an external 3rd party library, then a new instance of the component will be created every time the statement is executed. Autofac doesn't have a role.

Are my assumptions going into the right direction or am I completely wrong?

Regards, Matthias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autofac does not control and is not "aware" of object instances that it does not resolve. When you register a dependency as a singleton, that tells Autofac how to resolve the dependency - to reuse the same instance. In the meantime you could create any number of instances of the same class.

Registering a dependency as a singleton doesn't actually make the specified class a singleton. With a "real" singleton only one instance of the class can exist, because every call to get an instance returns the same instance. Registering the dependency as a singleton just tells the container to behave as if the class is a singleton, reusing one instance rather than creating new ones.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the clarifications. I understood now.

Comment: What I like about this is that we get the benefit of using a singleton (using a single instance rather than creating multiple) without having to write the class as an actual singleton.